# Remove extra spaces from entire sentence

Tags: r, string, trim, stringr

I have below variable

```
sen <- "I have a    sentence  "
```

I just want to remove spaces from above sentence (all of spaces, beginning end & middle), I know how to use `str_trim(sen)`, but that only removes beginning & end spaces.I want to get rid of middle as well

Required Output "I have a sentence"

Comment: `gsub(" ","","I have a    sentence  ")`

Comment: Thank you this helps, but does this remove only extra spaces & not all spaces ?

Comment: No, this removes all spaces, since in your question you stated `all of spaces`.

Comment: I am sorry I mean remove all extra spaces, sorry for confusion

Comment: Agree, Your way of writing in Question is confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck because there is exact same function in stringr package str_squish()

this should do what you want to achieve

```
library(stringr)
sen <- "I have a    sentence  "
str_squish(sen)
print(sen)
```

Output: "I have a sentence"

Answer (score 3):

We could use `gsub` to replace more than one space with one space. We wrap it in `trimws` to remove spaces present at the start and end of the string.

```
trimws(gsub("\\s+", " ", sen))
#[1] "I have a sentence"
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not very strong in regular expression, any helpful guide for that

Comment: @Artika https://www.regular-expressions.info/ seems to be a good resource.